# Getting segmentation fault 11 error in terminal

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a chat application.

In that whenever I try to start a chat connection giving a username, it starts properly and begins listening on an ip address. But, whenever I try to add another user to that connection by using the ip address of the main user, I get `Segmentation Fault: 11` on that terminal, and

```
NOTICE abc has joined on 10.0.0.2:52332

NOTICE abc has left chat or crashed
```

on the main user's terminal, simultaneously. Why is this happening? Can anybody help me out with this?

EDIT:
When I run it with valgrind, I get the following:

```
==22843== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22843== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22843== Using Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22843== Command: ./a.out abc 10.0.0.2:61488
==22843== 
--22843-- UNKNOWN host message [id 412, to mach_host_self(), reply 0x30f]
--22843-- UNKNOWN host message [id 222, to mach_host_self(), reply 0x30f]
--22843-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option
--22843-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 2 times)
--22843-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 4 times)
--22843-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 8 times)
==22843== Invalid read of size 1
==22843==    at 0x100341879: strtol_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==22843==    by 0x10002222A: main (chat.cpp:1765)
==22843==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==22843== 
==22843== 
==22843== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==22843==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==22843==    at 0x100341879: strtol_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==22843==    by 0x10002222A: main (chat.cpp:1765)
==22843==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==22843==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==22843==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==22843==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==22843==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==22843== 
==22843== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22843==     in use at exit: 46,007 bytes in 485 blocks
==22843==   total heap usage: 599 allocs, 114 frees, 61,582 bytes allocated
==22843== 
==22843== LEAK SUMMARY:
==22843==    definitely lost: 128 bytes in 2 blocks
==22843==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22843==      possibly lost: 14,034 bytes in 123 blocks
==22843==    still reachable: 31,845 bytes in 360 blocks
==22843==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22843== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==22843== 
==22843== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22843== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Killed: 9
```

I don't know what it means.

Comment: It is operating system specific (probably your OS is Linux or some POSIX, e.g. MacOSX). Do you have the source code of the application? Is it yours? Then compile it with debugging info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and enable core dump and/or use the `gdb` debugger.

Comment: If you don't have the source code, then it is going to be hell to debug.  You should contact the suppliers of the pre-compiled code to get them to fix the issue.  A crash is not acceptable behevaiour.  It might make the new connection work (best), decline the new connection (next best), or stop under control logging the problem (less good), but a crash is not really acceptable.

Comment: Also, I recommend using valgrind.  Compile with -g as recommended by comment above and then do `valgrind` followed by the executable file and its command-line arguments.

Comment: I do have the source code but it is too big to fit here. :/ So I added the sending thread's code, where I assume the problem could be. Any ideas?

Comment: Wrong tag.  I changed the language tag to c++. Good luck.

Comment: @EamonnO'Brien-Strain Could you look at my edit tin the question?

Comment: You need to *understand* the C++ source code and improve it. Learn how to use the debugger. You might need days or weeks of work. Run your application under `gdb`. Enable core dumps. When you got one, do a post-mortem analysis with `gdb`.  BTW, you should read some good C++ programming book, since your C++ style is quite poor.

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind points to a problem on line 1765 of chat.cpp, in a call to the strtol_l function.

It looks like you may be passing in a NULL pointer as the string argument of that function.  I suggest checking that string variable and making sure that it is set to a valid non-null string value before calling strtol_l.

**Update:**
You have deleted your code from the question, and I cannot remember exactly what it was, but it was something like:

```
recvdTokens = strtok(something, ";;;");
client.receivedSeqNum = atoi(recvdTokens);
```

You should instead do something like:

```
recvdTokens = strtok(something, ";;;");
if (recvdTokens) {
  // token found
  client.receivedSeqNum = atoi(recvdTokens);
}
```

You also might need to add an `else` section to take care of the case when no token found.

Comment: But there is no strtol_l in the program. :o

Comment: Also, I added the connection timeout thread code in the question with line 1765 marked.

Comment: What Is on line 1765? The strtol_l maybe hidden in a macro or inlined function.

Comment: atoi must call strtol_l, so your problem is that strtok can return NULL, and you need to handle that and not pass a NULL to atoi

Comment: You mean change this line client.receivedSeqNum = atoi(recvdTokens); to client.receivedSeqNum = atoi(strtol_l); ?

Comment: But, there is no strtol_l. When I do that it gives me an error saying no matching function for call to atoi.

Comment: @MarthaPears: No! But you really need to take days to read more about C++ programming and then improve your code. We can't help debugging every bug inside it!

Comment: No, I mean change the code to not call atoi when recvdTokens is NULL.